# Array of objects to string jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Is there a shorter notation to do the following code in jQuery? 
I would like to log the html content of all paragraphs.

```
var array = $('p').get();
$.each(array, function(i, val)
{
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: what information do you want to be displayed in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the content of paragraphs?

`console.log($('p').text())`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
console.log(array.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $.each(($('p').get()), function(i, val)
{
    console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain your code :

```
$('p').each(function (){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: `this` will refer to the actual HTMLElement. You will need to use `this.innerHTML` and not `this.html()`.

Comment: Edited my answer to use the JQuery's `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of format you expect you might try:

```
array.toSTring()
```

This would result in the array elements separated by ", "

Answer (score 0):

you can literally just do:

```
console.log($('p').get());
```

Answer (score 0):

try map()

```
 var pArray=$('p').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(pArray);
```